# Looping through a list using foreach

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0

I have a project that requires me to populate User information along with their personal information.
So far, I was able to loop through a list of users and personal information, but I was not able to populate null values.

For example:

```
public List<UserDetailModel> UserInformation()
{
    List<UserDetailModel> userdetails = new List<UserDetailModel>();

    var user = _context.User.Where(x => x.Id > 0).ToList()

    foreach(var item in user)
    {
        var personaldetails = _context.PersonalDetails.Where(x => item.PId == x.PId).ToList();

        foreach (var item2 in personaldetails)
        {
            UserDetailModel userModel = new UserDetailModel();

            userModel.UserId = item.UserId;
            userModel.Name = item.UserName;
            userModel.PhoneNumber = item.Number;

            userModel.CreditCardNumber = item2.CCNumber;
            userModel.SIN = item2.SinNumber;

            userdetails.Add(userModel);
        }
    }
    return userdetails;
}
```

What I'm expecting is:

```
"userId": 1,
"name": "john"
"phoneNUmber": 123-123-1234,
"creditCardNumber": 44455544445554545,
"sin": 9589898568

"userId": 1,
"name": "john"
"phoneNUmber": ,
"creditCardNumber": 44455544445554545,
"sin": 9589898568


"userId": 1,
"name": "john"
"phoneNUmber": 123-123-1234,
"creditCardNumber": ,
"sin": 9589898568


"userId": 1,
"name": "john"
"phoneNUmber": 123-123-1234,
"creditCardNumber": 44455544445554545,
"sin":
```

But what I'm getting with the above code is:

```
"userId": 1,
"name": "john"
"phoneNUmber": 123-123-1234,
"creditCardNumber": 44455544445554545,
"sin": 9589898568
```

How can I get all users along with their null values?

Comment: Can you provide the implementations for the models contained in `_context.User` and `_context.PersonalDetails`? I'm also assuming you are using entity framework?

Comment: You are looking up all users where the id is not null (this doesnt make sense, why would a user not have an ID), then for every user you are looking up all the PersonalDetails where the id is not null, i mean if you say it to your self it wont even sound right.  then you ask `How can I get all users along with their null values` what null values? please spend some time properly describing your schema and what you are wanting to achieve in ubiquitous and specific language

Comment: Do you have any example of the input data being used?

Comment: I just updated my code.

Comment: Your function is not returning anything, but it should. Does your code actually run? And what is the point of returning a list of UserDetailModel , and not the list of PersonalDetails directly from your context?

Comment: There's no ASP.NET here, I very much doubt this is .NET 2.0. Are you maybe using Entity Framework? Which version? Maybe update the tags to reflect what this question is actually about.

Comment: This is a separate trip to the database for every user. You should be able to **join** the queries together, so you only end up with _one loop_ and _one trip to the database_. It'll improve performance by an order of magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the logic was not implemented correctly, Two loops not required seems,

```
Public List<UserDetailModel> UserInformation(){

List<UserDetailModel> userdetails = new List<UserDetailModel>();

var user = (from user in _context.User 
           join personal in _context.PersonalDetails 
           on user.PId equals personal.PId 
           Where user.Id>0).ToList();

foreach(var item in user)
{
     UserDetailModel userModel = new UserDetailModel();

        userModel.UserId = item.UserId;
        userModel.Name = item.UserName;
        userModel.PhoneNumber = item.Number;

        userModel.CreditCardNumber = item2.CCNumber;
        userModel.SIN = item2.SinNumber;

        userdetails.Add(userModel);
}
```

So when personal details null it won't enter in the loop.